# flex lexer : Which variable should I update after yytext change?

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to write a simple compiler. I am currently in the scanner part.
Concerning string token, I have the following rule in the flex file :

`\"([^\\\n]|\\.)*\"         { clean_string(); return TK_STRING; }`

It works perfectly (this is not the question). clean_string function is called to removed leading and trailing " and to transform \n and \t to their corresponding ascii character.

```
int clean_string () {
  char * mystr;

  mystr=strdup(yytext+1) ; // copy yytext and remove leading "
  if (! mystr) return 1;
  mystr[yyleng-2]='\0'; // remove trailing "
  for (int i=0, j=0; i<=strlen(mystr); i++, j++) { // "<=" and not "<" to get /0, i : mystr indice and j : yytext indice
    if (mystr[i]=='\\') {
      i++;
      if (mystr[i]=='n')        yytext[j]='\n';
      else if (mystr[i]=='t')   yytext[j]='\t';
      else yytext[j]=mystr[i];
    }
    else yytext[j]=mystr[i];
  }
  yyleng=strlen(yytext);
  free(mystr);
  return 0 ;
}
```

It also works perfectly.

My question is the following :
At the end of the function, I update yyleng because yytext has changed. I wonder if I have another variable to update to avoid some unexpected behavior in another part of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use `yymore()` in your action (and evidently, you do not), the flex-generated scanner does not require `yyleng` to reflect the length of `yytext`. You can modify `yyleng` in any way, or you can modify the contents of `yytext` between index 0 and index `yyleng-1`, including making it shorter.

Having said that, you need to be aware that the contents of `yytext` are only stable until the next time you call `yylex`. In almost all applications, particularly if you are planning on using the scanner from a parser with lookahead (such as a parser generated by yacc/bison), you will want the scanner to use a *copy* of the contents of `yytext`. In particular, yacc/bison generated scanners expect to find the semantic value of tokens (that is, the token string or some value derived from it) in some member of the union `yylval`, generally in the form of a pointer.

So I'd strongly recommend that your function put the desired string contents into  `mystr` and then return it (rather than freeing it immediately), and that the action place the pointer in a place where the parser can use it. That will require only a minor modification to your code and will make the scanner usable with a yacc/bison-generated parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Concerning bison, you are right. It is my next step to build the AST. Perhaps, I will ask new questions.